# 3D Cube Problem! Part 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, catransform3d

I have created a 3D cube in iphone using `CALayer's`. Now I wanted to rotate that cube(`CALayer`) at `90˚` when user double taps on it.

I was able to rotate that cube(`CALayer`) to `90˚` once but when I double tap the cube(`CALayer`) is not rotating.

Here is the code that I used to rotate the cube(`CALayer`)

```
CATransform3D x = CATransform3DRotate(currentLayer.sublayerTransform, M_PI / 2, 0, 0, 1);
currentLayer.transform = x;
```

Can anyone help in this. What I'm doing wrong.

---

PS. For the people who are wondering how I got the degree sign then here is the trick

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because you are not changing the angle of rotation .... to understand this lets say you are passing M_PI/2 each time to that method .... so `CATransform3DRotate` do not rotate it to `next 90˚` rather it rotate the layer to the specified angle in this case its 90... so you are not getting any chage because it already at `90˚` ..... so to get correct result do this

```
static float angle = M_PI / 2;//dont make it static rather make it a global variable
angle += M_PI / 2;
CATransform3D x = CATransform3DRotate(currentLayer.sublayerTransform,angle, 0, 0, 1);
currentLayer.transform = x;
```

Comment: But i thought that is in the case of `CATransform3DMakeRotation`

Comment: You may also find using a CATransformLayer (if not already) will help.