# 3D Cube problem, Part 2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, cube

This is my 2nd Question on 3D cubes in iphone using CALayer, Core Animation framework, written in Objective-c. For my first question please visit here [3D Cube Problem! Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275672/3d-cube-problem-part-1).

I am using Brad Larsons code to rotate my 3D cube from this link

http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/22/3-d-rotation-without-trackball

The problem is my cube is rotating in x axis along the pink line shown in the figure.

[image]

But I want to rotate it around x axis along the black line shown in the figure.
Now in my code I dont have any pink line or black line drawn on my view so can some one please help me with this.

If it helps here is the code for rotating my cube in `touchesMoved:` method

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CATransform3D currentTransform = currentLayer.sublayerTransform;
    CGFloat displacementInX = location.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat displacementInY = previousLocation.y - location.y;
    CGFloat totalRotation = sqrt(displacementInX * displacementInX + displacementInY * displacementInY);
    CGFloat x = (displacementInX/totalRotation) * currentTransform.m12 + (displacementInY/totalRotation) * currentTransform.m11;
    CATransform3D rotationalTransform = CATransform3DRotate(currentTransform, totalRotation * M_PI / 180.0, x, y, 0);
    currentLayer.sublayerTransform = rotationalTransform;
}
```

previousLocation is a `CGPoint` initialized in `touchesBegan:` method, and currentLayer is `CALayer` where I have created this cube.

Thanks for your help.

PS. If you want to know how I created this cube then let me know

Comment: I'd love to know how you created the cube. I'm trying to do a similar thing to you. Any progress so far?

Comment: i have scraped the project but i think i could give you the code to make a cube in quartz core.

Comment: Hey, I got a very similar code, rotating `CALayer` in 3D and all, but I solved the problem by changing the `anchorPoint` as Simon Lee suggested. You must have done something wrong with it. Please share layer construction code, and I'll solve it... Or, I can do my own cube if required.

Comment: thats not true i have tried it and everything still the results are same. May be there is something else i am missing out.

Comment: So, are you gonna share the code, or should I build a 3D cube and rotate it?

Comment: I will do that 2day as i dont have it with me at the office. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did u solved this Robin? can u share the code for transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to translate the layers first prior to rotating them.

Instead of picking a pivot/anchor point you can use CATransform3DTranslate first to translate the layers away from their natural origin, and use CATransform3DRotate after that.

It would help to take a look at how you build your cube in order to pinpoint how it can be implemented.

Comment: Let me try that and get back to you on this one.

Comment: Hey that actually worked, thanks for your help. Didn't know it would be that simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Set the andchorPoint to the centre; if dealing with a CALayer then...

```
[myLayer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];
```

Comment: No still rotating at along that pink line in the figure